# How to properly handle 2D tiled collision with fake movement?

Tags: java, collision, velocity, tiled

I'm trying to implement collision detection on my Java 2D Tiled game. This is my first attempt on game development, so please don't mind the messy code.

The following method checks the user input and sets a fake X and Y to check if a future movement will result in collision (axis-aligned collision). The steps are:

1. Set fakeX to be player.x + 1
2. Check collision with fakeX
3. if collision is false using fakeX, update player.x to be the same as fakeX
4. If collision is true, do nothing with player.x and set back fakeX to be player.x

The thing is, when I try to increase the "velocity" by changing + 1 to + 2, it behaves kinda weird, leaving a gap between the player and the wall. It is probably "bouncing back really fast". This gap makes it unable to fit in the hole on top.

Any thoughts on this? Maybe things are in a wrong order? Am I missing something?

[the gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r8Pw.png)

the code for moving right:

```
public void checkInput() {      
    if (player.moveRight) {
        player.fakeX = player.x + 2;
        player.getCollisionBox().setLocation(player.fakeX, player.y);
        checkCollisionWhenMoving();
        if (!player.willCollide) {
            player.x = player.fakeX;
        } else {
            player.fakeX = player.x;
            player.willCollide = false;
        }
        player.getCollisionBox().setLocation(player.x, player.y);
    } 
}
```

checkCollisionWhenMoving() uses the player collision box to check for collisions. The code for collision detection itself is working really well. the checkInput() method runs every time.

Comment: So, if the user is to move two places, then you should need to check a collision for each location, if you detect a collision, you need to determine actually how far the use can move - this could be part of the detection, returning how many places the user "could" move before a collision occurs, which will be =< the desired amount of movement

Comment: @MadProgrammer after reading your comment a few times, I think I got what you mean, yet I dont know how to properly code this. Thanks for answering!